# What is the suggested approach to initialize positions of swarm elements in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I a currently trying to initialize a swarm of objects, each having its own (different) collider. My problem is, I don't know how to go about initializing the objects' position without them colliding.

I do know that collision detection happens via `OnCollisionEnter` etc. However, using this mechanism, I would need to implement some kind of callback mechanism. Or is there a way to check if an object collides with another one right after instantiating it?

Comment: What type of collider does that gameobject have? Also, what is the min max random position of the object?

Comment: The colliders are either boxes, spheres or capsules. The objects are positioned by placing them in a defined spawn point. As long as they collide with an existing object, all existing objects (except the newly created one) are moved away from the spawn point.

Comment: Ok. Why not update your question with what you currently have? That I can use to figure out what you are doing wrong or if it has to be re-written.

Comment: would it be OK to populate them in a "bullseye" matter? i.e choose a center point and them randomly create new objects on a point of each radius you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is (and the first options works like a charm because of previous experience):

- If there is a lot of objects, I would just let them collide with each other and then each time one object collides with another object, what I do is inside `OnCollisionEnter()` method in each object I would call a co-routine that waits for 1 or 2 seconds and then kill the velocity of the objects to zero (`rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero`) (assuming that they have RigidBodies).
  NOTE: This option can also be used for just a few object, as long as you don't mind the collision detection.
- If there are only a few objects (and you want to avoid collision detection), I would keep the position of previous objects in the an array, and when instantiating a new object I would first generate a random position (create `Vector3` with random x, y and z) and if the position is not in the array of previous positions, only then instantiate the game object, if the position is repeat generate a new random position.

Personally I like the result of the first one more since everything looks more randomly placed (because of the unpredictable collisions). I have used the first method to create a huge asteroid field (~10,000 2D asteroid) and it works very well.

Comment: The first solution sounds interesting, I am also trying to generate an asteroid field, so I'll give it a try, thanks :)